# How can I reverse the value of the output?

Tags: python

Let's put int 5 as a sample input; in my code its expressed as this:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(0, n):
   n = n - 1
   print(n**2)
```

I get an output as:

```
16
9
4
1
0
```

Instead **I want to reverse the result to:**

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

How do you go about solving this problem?

Comment: `print(i ** 2)`

Comment: `print(*[i**2 for i in range(n)], sep='\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will reverse the output:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    print(i**2)
```

It will loop from 0 to your inputted `n` value, printing it's square at each iteration. This also negates the need for the `n = n - 1` line.

Output:

```
0 ** 2
1 ** 2
.
.
.
n ** 2
```